# Version and Build numbers not showing up while archiving the build in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am archiving the build to be submitted to the App Store, but version and build not showing up. I have attached the screenshot for the same. After exporting the .ipa when I am submitting the app via Application Loader I am getting this error. "The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleShortVersionString key." I have already added these details to info.plist file as below.

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.1</string>
```

The info.plist file is also in the root folder. I have two separate targets for iPhone and iPad applications.

[image: version and build not showing up]

Comment: did you  attached your device while build ?

Comment: Check in your project settings, in target how is that given

Comment: @KKRocks Yes, I have attached the real device archiving the build.

Comment: @Sivajee Battina Yes, it is the same there too.

Comment: Then remove it from mac then clean your project with command + shift + k ....and build with generic device again.

Comment: Looks strange @RajanKambaliya.  delete those entries once and try to set it from target settings

Comment: Not working yet. @KKRocks  :(

Comment: Not working @Sivajee Battina :(

Comment: also check plist file where you made your changes .

Comment: It is the same.

Comment: I am also getting blank value for
       NSString * version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
       objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

       NSString * build = [[NSBundle mainBundle]objectForInfoDictionaryKey: 
       (NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];

Answer (score 0):

I found one script as below.

```
git=$(sh /etc/profile; which git)
git_release_version=$("$git" describe --tags --always --abbrev=0)
number_of_commits=$("$git" rev-list master | wc -l | tr -d ' ')
target_plist="$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
dsym_plist="$DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/$DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME/Contents/Info 
.plist"

for plist in "$target_plist" "$dsym_plist"; do
if [ -f "$plist" ]; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $number_of_commits" 
"$plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString 
${git_release_version#*v}" "$plist"
fi
done
```

I was able to solve the issue after removing this script. This script is for auto updating of version and build number. I do not know why this script was causing the issue.